# Download certificates: gnutls or openssl

Tags: ssl-certificate

I need to download a certificate from a site. Up to now, I've been using `gnutls` command in order to get it.

```
$ gnutls-cli --save-cert=ra-sec.pem vault.ra-sec.svc
```

I've found out I', able to use `openssl`:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect vault.ra-sec.svc:443
```

Nevertheless, both downloaded certificates are not the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your server probably uses Server Name Indication (SNI), which `gnutls` (like most modern SSL/TLS implementations) sends automatically, but `openssl s_client` does not by default; it needs you to additionally specify `-servername $host`

Answer (score 2):

Openssl does **not** automatically send a hostname in the ClientHello message and then a request will return the default TLS certificate rather than the hostname specific certificate if the server is configured with multiple TLS certificates.

To get similar output to `gnutls-cli` you probably need to use the [`-servername`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/s_client.html)  and [`-showcerts`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/s_client.html)  options:

> **`-servername name`**
>              Set the TLS SNI (Server Name Indication) extension in the ClientHello message.
>
> **`-showcerts`**
>   display the whole server certificate chain: normally only the server certificate itself is displayed.

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -servername vault.ra-sec.svc -connect vault.ra-sec.svc:443
```

Answer (score 0):

gnutls version

```
gnutls-bin --print-cert vault.ra-sec.svc:443 | certtool --certificate-info
```